# MySQL query to find unique records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
+----+-------+---------+
| id | media | status  |
+----+-------+---------+
|  1 | FOO   | ACTIVE  |
|  1 | FOO   | PENDING |
| >1 | BAR   | ACTIVE  |
|  2 | FOO   | ACTIVE  |
|  2 | FOO   | PENDING |
| >3 | BAR   | ACTIVE  |
+----+-------+---------+
```

What I need to get is a list of `id`, which have `ACTIVE` records with certain `media`, but have no `PENDING` record with the same `media`. In my example `id=1` have covered `FOO`, but uncovered `BAR`.

So the resulting table should be:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

The only solution I see is to create two tables with `ACTIVE` and `PENDING` records separately, then find records, which are only in `ACTIVE` and not in `PENDING`. But I have no idea how to construct the request.

Please advise.

Comment: If an id has two media types, one with pending, one without, should it still be included?

Comment: Oh, my apologies. If `id` has only PENDING `media` then it is not included.

Comment: I'm asking about where *one* id has two *different* media types, and one has pending but the other is only active. See my answer for the practical difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a NOT EXISTS clause (a NOT IN would also work).

```
select distinct id
from table t
where status = 'ACTIVE'
and not exists (select null
                  from table
                  where t.id = id and t.media = media
                  and status = 'PENDING')
```

see [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e70b30/1)

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with `group by` and `having`, because this is a very flexible way to formulate this type of query:

```
select id
from table t
group by id, media
having sum(status = 'ACTIVE') > 0 and
       sum(status = 'PENDING') = 0;
```

Comment: what if OP has more than 2 statuses ?? like active , pending , expired, hold?

Comment: @timus2001 . . . This will work as written.  And, it is easy to add additional rules, such as at most one expired and three on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Using a LEFT JOIN:-

```
SELECT a.id
FROM some_table a
LEFT OUTER JOIN some_table b
ON a.id = b.id
AND a.media = b.media
AND a.status = 'ACTIVE'
AND b.status = 'PENDING'
WHERE b.id IS NULL
```

This self joins the table, one for active and one for pending. Checks that b.id IS NULL to check there is no match.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
  FROM t
 GROUP BY id, media
HAVING MAX(status) = 'ACTIVE';
```

This assumes that an id that has a pending media should still be included if it also has a different media type without pending. If that's incorrect, or not applicable, you can remove `DISTINCT` from the SELECT and `media` from the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP CONCAT

```
select id from tbl group by media,id 
having group_concat(status)='active'
```

Comment: This will include rows containing only `PENDING`.

Comment: Active pending whatever ... i will fiddle it tomorrow..its late night here :)

Comment: Not sure what unique sets have to do with anything, but your first query will definitely include `id`s that only have `PENDING` statuses.

Comment: Yes.. op has not mentioned he need it only for active ...this work for any unique set ... if op need specific he can append where clause at last... i prefer generic sql rather than hardcoded..think before downvoting

Comment: edited ... OP just commented that he exclusively need for active only

Comment: earlier in his question those things werent mentioned.. i was fooled here :)

Comment: The answer is only correct if we assume a maximum of one ACTIVE row per group.